# How to install Python from an .asc file?

Tags: python, installation

I want to download Python 3.5.4(https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-354/) but the Python site only gives out .asc files instead of .exe files.

I tried opening the .asc file with Adobe Acrobat Reader but i get an error telling me the file is damaged.
It really comes down to knowing how to execute an .asc file.

Comment: The ASC download links are listed in the "GPG" column. Try the "Version" column, which contains the binaries.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably downloading the [GPG signature](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179209/what-are-the-gpg-signatures), not the actual Python distribution. Please find the correct download link in the *Version* column.

Answer (score 2):

The asc files aren't the downloads - they're GPG signatures (allowing you to verify the corresponding download files haven't been interfered with by some sinister intermediary).

The downloads files are in the left column of the "files" table - they're .exe (for windows), pkg (for OS-X), or zip/gz archives (for source code).

Answer (score 1):

You have to run "Windows x86-64 executable installer" under "files" at the bottom of the page. Hope it helps!